# how to express an item attribute in the "then" in json-schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following json schema:

```
 {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "myJsonSchema",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "flag": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "myArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/ArrayItem"
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "ArrayItem": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "itemAttribute1": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": ""
        },
        "itemAttribute2": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "flag": {
          "const": true
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "myArray": {
          "items": {
            "required": "itemAttribute1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to validate that when the flag is set to true, then the field "itemAttribute" is required. How I can achieve that ?

**Examples:**

This json should be valid:

```
{
    "flag" : true,
      "myArray" : [
        {
          "itemAttribute1" : "c",
          "itemAttribute2" : "d"
        }
      ]
}
```

While this json should not valid (because since flag=true, itemAttribute1 becomes required):

```
{
    "flag" : true,
      "myArray" : [
        {
          "itemAttribute2" : "d"
        }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gregsdennis explained, each of `if` and `then` takes a JSON schema as its value.
I modified `if` and `then` part in your original schema.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "myJsonSchema",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "flag": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "myArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/ArrayItem"
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "ArrayItem": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "itemAttribute1": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": ""
        },
        "itemAttribute2": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "flag": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "myArray": {
            "items": {
              "required": ["itemAttribute1"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if`, `then`, and `else` keywords take full schemas as their values. To express object properties within them, you need to nest those property names under a `properties` keyword with in the `if` and `then` as you have them.

Additionally, unless you plan on adding more subschemas under the `allOf`, that's not necessary.

Comment: I am able to do it with an simple object but I cannot find the correct way to express it when I am dealing with an array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you update the question with an example of the instance (data) you're trying to validate?